# C# Update record in datatable validation

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a datatable record as below

```
Id  Code    Desc
 0   A       AA
 0   B       BB
```

When user add new record, all Id will be zero before save into database.  I want to validate the record user add in the datatable which not allow duplicate.

I got the class

```
 Class book

  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string Code {get; set;}
  public string Desc {get; set;}
  public bool IsEdit {get; set;}
```

I do the following

```
var match = BookTable.Where(r => r.Code == txtCode.Text)
if(match.Count() > 0)
{
     MessageBox.Show("Code exist");
     return;
}
```

If user double click Code B and change the code to Code A, it will prompt the message.  If user add new record and key in code as A, it also will prompt message where it work fine.

The problem I face now is when user double click the record A and only modify the description, when click save, it will say Code exist since the code A already in datatable.

How I can skip checking if it is modify the same record?

Comment: Keep track of the state of a record and perform that check only if the Code property has changed (the User modified that Property/Column). If *double clicks* means you enter  Edit mode of a DataGridView cell, you have no problem to identify the before-edit state of a record (Cells have `CellBeginEdit` and `CellEndEdit` events).

Comment: any coding sample for reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check with your ID.

```
     //First, when you insert an object into your database, you should get the ID of your object and assign it to your gridview row. 


    //For exemple:
      var book= new Book();
      book.Code = "myCode";
      ..
      ..
      using(MyDataContext dc = new MyDataContext())
      {
        dc.Books.Add(book);
        dc.SaveChanges(); //Here, your object gets an ID if auto.
        myGridViewRow.Cells[index].Value = book.ID; //And then, you have not row without ID. 
      }


     //This code will check for a new record.
     var match = BookTable.Any(r => r.Code == txtCode.Text); 
     match will be true or false if there is a record with your txtCode.Text.        

     //And this one will check for an existing record
     var match = BookTable.Any(r => r.Code == txtCode.Text && r.ID != IDOfARecord);
     //This time match will be true if there is another record with the modified text. And thanks to r.ID != IDOfARecord condition, it will not check the modified record.
```

Comment: teh problem is the record no Id if it is newly add record.  If user choose the newly added record to edit the description, it will prompt the error

Comment: When the user add a new record, you should get the last added rows ID and update your gridviews row's ID. And then  you can check it.

Comment: if i not yet save the record into Db, how can do it?  No DbContext in my application.

Comment: In this case, you can add a tag to your object. To say Updated Or Inserted. When created, you set the tag = created, If the user updates the object, you set the tag= updated.

Comment: And check according the tag.